# Change calculator not returning correct answer

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble with a program I have to write for an exercise in my uni course. I have to create a change calculator that asks the user for the price of an item and how much they've put into the machine but my program returns the wrong answer in the amount of change given back to the user. What have I done wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int cost;
    int money;
    int change;
    int remainder;
    int fiftyP;
    int twentyP;
    int tenP;
    int fiveP;
    int twoP;
    int oneP;

    printf("What is the price of the item: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &cost);
    printf("How much have you put into the machine: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &money);
    while (cost > 99 || money > 100)
    {
        printf("Please enter no larger than 99p for cost and 100p for money inserted\n");
        printf("What is the price of the item: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &cost);
        printf("How much have you put into the machine: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &money);
    }

    change = money - cost;
    fiftyP = change / 50;
    remainder = change % 50;
    twentyP = remainder / 20;
    remainder = change % 20;
    tenP = remainder / 10;
    remainder= change % 10;
    fiveP = remainder / 5;
    remainder = change % 5;
    twoP = remainder / 2;
    remainder = change % 2;
    oneP = remainder / 1;


    printf("Number of 50p coins is %d\nNumber of 20p coins is %d\nNumber of 10p coins is %d\nNumber of 5p coins is %d\nNumber of 2p coins is %d\nNumber of 1p coins is %d ", fiftyP, twentyP, tenP, fiveP, twoP, oneP);
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: "but my program returns the wrong." --> What the the input, what was the wrong output, what was expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calculating the value of `fiftyP`, you're  using `change` to calculate each successive remainder while using `remainder` to calculate each coin count.  You should instead be using `change` in all places:

```
change = money - cost;
fiftyP = change / 50;
change= change % 50;
twentyP = change/ 20;
change= change% 20;
tenP = change/ 10;
change= change% 10;
fiveP = change/ 5;
change= change% 5;
twoP = change/ 2;
change= change% 2;
oneP = change/ 1;
```